# Dealing with high noise data?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, noise

I am working with sensors on trucks which give me data with a lot of noise. The goal is to make a prediction to prevent failure in the system. I am having trouble with this for several reasons:

1. The high noise sometimes gives me values that would raise an alarm but in reality does not affect the process in a way that the trucks should stop running, such as hitting a pothole and more.
2. The data includes down time which greatly affects averaging of data.

My question is what techniques I can use to reduce the noise of the data.

Comment: What are the signals for? Triggering TCS or... I mean, you could set the signal to 0 and that's definitely not noisy! Can you just set the tolerance higher for triggering an "event"?

Comment: Well I did ask this as a broad question because there are 282 different sensors and "events" can be due to anything really. But In an effort to make this more relatable I will focus on the cooling system. There are currently 9 sensors that is used to gauge the over health of the cooling system. Engine coolant preasure, Engine Intc Preasure, Engine RMP, Engine Air Temp, Lube Temp Fan Temp. Some of these are doubled for hi and low temps.